# Find all the square roots of $11$ in $\mathbb Z_{35}$ by CRT.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I understand what the Chinese remainder theorem is. However I am not sure how to apply it to my question. Can someone explain please?

Answer (score 2):

We apply CRT as explained in the Remark below: first we compute the square roots $\!\bmod 5\ \&\ 7$ then we take all possible combinations of roots and lift them to roots $\!\bmod 35\,$ using CRT.

$$\begin{align}&\overbrace{{\rm mod}\ 5\!:\,\ x^2\equiv 11\equiv 1}^{5\mid (x-1)(x+1)\iff \color{#0a0}{5\mid x-1}\ {\rm or}\ \color{#0a0}{5\mid x+1}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}\!\iff \color{#0a0}{x\equiv \pm1}\equiv: \color{#0af}{a}\\[.2em] 
&{\rm mod}\ 7\!:\,\ x^2\equiv 11\equiv 4\iff x\equiv \pm 2\equiv: \color{#0af}{b}\end{align}\qquad\qquad$$

---

Next we solve the system $\, x\equiv \color{#0af}a\pmod{\! 5}\,$ and $\,x\equiv \color{#0af}b\pmod{\! 7}\,$ for  $\rm\color{#0af}{generic}$ (any)  $\rm\color{#0af}{a,b}$

${\rm mod}\ 5\!:\ a \equiv x\equiv b+7\color{#c00}k\equiv b+2k\iff 2k\equiv a\!-\!b\!\overset{\times\,(-2)}\iff \color{#c00}{k\equiv 2(b\!-\!a)}$

therefore $\ x = b+7\color{#c00}k = b+7(\color{#c00}{2(b\!-\!a)+5n}) = b+14(b\!-\!a)+35n$

---

For example the case $\, a,b \equiv \color{#0a0}1, 2\,$ yields that $\, x = 2 + 14(2\!-\!1) = 16+35n$

Its negation  $\,{-}16\equiv 19\pmod{\!35}\,$ is also a square root (case $\,a,b \equiv -1,-2 \equiv -[1,2])$

Do similarly for  $\,a,b \equiv \color{#0af}{-1,2}\,$ and its negative $\,1,-2\,$ to get all $\,4\,$ square roots, yielding

$$ (x\!-\!16)(x\!+\!16) \equiv x^2\!-\!11\equiv (x^2\!-\!\color{#0af}9)(x^2\!+\!9)\pmod{\!35}\qquad$$

**Remark** $\ $ If $\,m,n\,$ are coprime then, by CRT, solving a polynomial $\,f(x)\equiv 0\pmod{\!mn}\,$ is equivalent to solving $\,f(x)\equiv 0\,$ both $\!\bmod m\,$ and $\!\bmod n.\,$ By CRT, each combination of a root $\,r_i\bmod m\,$ and a root $\,s_j\bmod n\,$ corresponds to a unique root $\,t_{ij}\bmod mn\,$ i.e.

$$\begin{eqnarray} f(x)\equiv 0\!\!\!\pmod{\!mn}\!\!&\overset{\small\rm CRT\!}\iff& \begin{array}{}f(x)\equiv 0\pmod{\! m}\\f(x)\equiv 0\pmod{\! n}\end{array} \\ 
&\iff&  \begin{array}{}x\equiv r_1,\ldots,r_k\pmod{\!m}\phantom{I^{I^{I^I}}}\\x\equiv s_1,\ldots,s_\ell\pmod{\!n}\end{array}\\ 
&\iff& \left\{ \begin{array}{}x\equiv r_i\pmod{\! m}\\x\equiv s_j\pmod{\! n}\end{array} \right\}_{\begin{array}{}1\le i\le k\\ 1\le j\le\ell\end{array}}^{\phantom{I^{I^{I^I}}}}\\
&\overset{\small\rm CRT\!\!}\iff&\, \left\{\, x\equiv t_{i j}\!\!\!\!\pmod{\!mn} \right\}_{\begin{array}{}1\le i\le k\\ 1\le j\le\ell\end{array}}\\
\end{eqnarray}\qquad\qquad\qquad$$

Comment: Dubuqe Firstly just to clarify do we have mod 5 and 7 because 5 and 7 are the prime factors of 35? Also I understand your first 3 lines, however I do not understand how the CRT is being used to solve for $x$ after that. Could you clarify please?

Comment: @Jed Yes re: factors. The CRT calculation is just solving the listed  system for general $\,a,b\,$ then substituting the $4$ specific $a,b$ for the roots. This is one of many ways to do CRT. If you know another than you can use that instead. Or if you say more precisely what is not clear then I can elaborate.

Comment: Is x supposed to denote the square roots I am looking for? If so, will I not get one value for x as opposed to multiple, if I use the CRT?

Comment: @jed I added a remark explaining how CRT works here.

Comment: From what you have written am i right in saying that in my case 1 and -1 are equal to $r_1$ and $r_2$ respectively, whilst 2 and -2 are equal to $s_1$ and $s_2$ respectively? If so I am still not sure how to use this to find the square roots I need?

Comment: @Jed Right. I did CRT on $\,(a,b) = (r_1,s_1)\equiv  (1,2)\ {\rm mod}\ (5,7)\,$ yielding the root $\,16\pmod{35},\,$ since $16\equiv 1\pmod{5},\,$ and $\,16\equiv 2\pmod 7.\,$ There are $3$ other combinations but you can  cut the work in half by exploiting negation symmetry: $\,x^2\equiv 11\,\Rightarrow\, (-x)^2\equiv 11,\,$ so if $\,x\,$ is a root then so is $\,-x,\,$ and $\, x\equiv (a,b) \iff -x\equiv (-a,-b)\ \ {\rm mod}\ (5.7)\ \ $