# How quickly can we use Chinese remainder theorem to find a value?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, asymptotics, intuition, chinese-remainder-theorem

If we have a value $x$ that is known modulo all primes less than $p$, how quickly can we determine its value?

In other words, we know $x \bmod 2$, $x \bmod 3$, $x \bmod 5$, etc...  We also know that $x$ is a natural number or $0$, i.e. $x$ is not negative..  How quickly, asymptotically, can we determine $x$, assuming $x$ is uniquely determined by the set of primes used?  I mean here that $x < 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot \cdots p$.  I'm looking for bounds in terms of $p$.

Comment: Is this specifically about computational complexity?

Comment: @JustKevin:  It is about computational complexity, but I saw it as more of a math question, than computational complexity.

Comment: Are you familiar with *mixed radix* reps such as $\, n = n_0 + 2(n_1 + 3(n_2 + 5(n_3 + \cdots)))\,?\ $ These may be more natural depending on you application.

Comment: @BillDubuque:  I'd seen the term, but didn't know it.  I'm probably stuck with using the congruences in the question, but I will definitely give mixed radix representation some thought.  This is for an algorithm I'm designing, and my current method is hard to change.  Thank you for your interest in this question, and for your ideas.  I wasn't sure where to post this question, but I'm very thankful for all the ideas here. :-)

Comment: @MattGroff If you describe what you're using this for then you might get other suggestions too. One place to lean about such is Knuth's TAOCP v.2 *Seminumerical Algorithms.*

Comment: @BillDubuque:  I'm using this for an algorithm in a research paper that I hope to one day publish, and I'm hesitant to give too many of my ideas away, without having published them first.  I still don't know enough about my ideas yet to even know if they're worth publishing, and I've never published before.  I would like to share my ideas, but again, I don't want to ruin my chance at publication, where I figure I can share my ideas.  So I find myself wanting to share, but I believe I shouldn't.  I hope this makes sense - some day I hope to share more...

Answer (score 3):

The [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) says that given relatively prime $\left\{p_i\right\}_{i=1}^n$ and any $\left\{x_i\right\}_{i=1}^n$ we can find an $x$ that satisfies
$$
x\equiv x_i\pmod{p_i}\tag{1}
$$
for all $i$ and that $x$ is unique mod $P=\prod\limits_{i=1}^np_i$.

To facilitate solving $(1)$ for each given $\left\{x_i\right\}_{i=1}^n$, we can compute $\left\{u_i\right\}_{i=1}^n$ so that
$$
\begin{align}
u_i&\equiv1\pmod{p_i}\\
u_i&\equiv0\pmod{P/p_i}
\end{align}\tag{2}
$$
by solving the equation
$$
a_ip_i+b_iP/p_i=1\tag{3}
$$
using the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), and setting $u_i=b_iP/p_i$.

Then, for any $\left\{x_i\right\}_{i=1}^n$,
$$
x=\sum_{i=1}^nx_iu_i\tag{4}
$$
satisfies $(1)$.

Comment: It would be helpful to state *explicitly* that you are simply applying one common form of CRT= Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: @BillDubuque: I am not sure what you are suggesting. $(3)$ is the solution to the CRT as given in $(4)$. We can do most of the work ahead of time if we know the set of primes.

Comment: The point is that many readers probably would not have realized that it is nothing but standard CRT without explicit mention. And, yes, of course one does not have to recompute what remains fixed in subsequent applications.

Comment: I have added a mention that $(4)$ is the CRT and given a link.

Comment: I think it would be much  clearer for beginners if you mentioned at the *start* that you are going to solve that system by the standard CRT method (with a link). thus providing context for what follows.

Comment: @BillDubuque: I have reorganized the answer, but it says exactly the same thing, except now I describe the CRT.

Comment: Great!  Readers of the long linked Wikipedia article should note that this construction of the solution is section titled "Existence (direct construction)."  See also [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1865413/242), as well as most any textbook in elementary number theory.  There are almost surely some expositions on this site that are better than the Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 1):

I have an equation for this.  I'm not sure about the complexity or if it's unique and I use some awkward notation.  But again we can't find a specific value for $x$ based on this information without all the primes, unless $p$ is the largest prime less than $x$ in which case those residues can't be chosen -- they are determined by the value for $x$.  However, with $x < p\#$, I will oblige.

Let $x \equiv x_i\pmod{p_i}$ and $x_i \in [0, p_i)$

$$x \equiv \Sigma_{p_i<p}{\{x_i(\frac{p\#}{p_i})[(\frac{p\#}{p_i})^{-1}_{\pmod{p_i}}]\}} \pmod{p\#}$$

Because $p\# \equiv 0 \pmod{p_i}$ for all the primes less than $p$, $\frac{p\#}{p_i} \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p_i}$, and rings of integers mod primes have integer inverses,

$$ (\frac{p\#}{p_i})[(\frac{p\#}{p_i})^{-1}_{\pmod{p_i}}] \equiv 1 \pmod{p_i}$$
$$ (\frac{p\#}{p_i})[(\frac{p\#}{p_i})^{-1}_{\pmod{p_i}}] \equiv 0 \pmod{p_j}$$

where $p_j \ne p_i$ and both are less than $p$.

I want it to be clear that the inverse taken is from the ring of integers mod $p_i$.  And therefore we've found $x$, conserving each residue.

Finding the inverse requires roughly i/2 steps, because the inverses are symmetric around (p+1)/2, and that step is carried out i times.  And finding primorial is i steps, but that has to be done at the beginning, no matter what.

So $O(n + n^2/2)$ is my best guess for complexity.

Comment: This is just the standard solution by CRT = Chinese Remainder Theorem. See my comment on Rob's answer.

Comment: Then I need to edit this.

Comment: There.  I added my answer for the complexity.  I don't understand your criticism, though @BillDubuque.

Comment: The point of my comment was simply to inform readers that you are using the standard CRT solution of the system of congruences. This deserves *explict* mention.

Comment: Ok, thanks Bill.