# Solutions of $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod N$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, roots-of-unity, quadratic-residues

I am stuck with this exercise:

> Show that $\forall s >0 \quad \exists N >0$ such that $$x^2 \equiv 1\pmod N$$ has more than $s$ solutions.

I think I cannot use the theory if quadratic residues, because the modulus is not prime, so maybe I must prove it with square roots or roots of unity, but I don't know how to approach it at all.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1262457/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2041335/242), which immediately yield the general idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Consider a square-free integer: $\;N=p_1p_2\dotsm p_r$. By the *Chinese Remainder theorem*, solving the equation $x^2\equiv 1\pmod N$ is equivalent to solving the set of congruences
$$\begin{cases}
x^2\equiv 1\pmod{p_1} \\ \quad\enspace\vdots\\x^2\equiv 1\pmod{p_r}
\end{cases}\iff 
\begin{cases}
x\equiv\pm 1\pmod{p_1} \\ \quad\,\vdots\\x \equiv \pm1\pmod{p_r}
\end{cases}$$
so there are $2^r$ solutions.

Comment: Is not $2^r$ the number of solutions?

Comment: Oops! Yes, of course. Sorry for the mistyping, and thank you for your pointing it!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $ $ Let $\,f(x) = x^2-1\,$ below and exploit the highlighted  $\rm\color{#c00}{multiplicativity}$ of  number of roots.

**Remark** $\ $ If $\,m,n\,$ are coprime then, by CRT, solving a polynomial $\,f(x)\equiv 0\pmod{\!mn}\,$ is equivalent to solving $\,f(x)\equiv 0\,$ mod $\,m\,$ & mod $\,n.\,$ By CRT, each combination of a root $\,r_i\,$ mod $\,m\,$ and a root $\,s_j\,$ mod $\,n\,$ corresponds to a *unique* root $\,t_{ij}\,$ mod $\,mn,\,$ i.e.

$$\begin{eqnarray} f(x)\equiv 0\!\!\!\pmod{mn}&\overset{\rm \large CRT\!\!}\iff& \begin{array}{}f(x)\equiv 0\pmod{\! m}\\f(x)\equiv 0\pmod{\! n}\end{array} \\ 
&\iff&  \begin{array}{}x\equiv r_1,\ldots,r_{\color{}{\large k}}\pmod{\! m},\phantom{I^{I^{I^I}}}\ \ \color{#c00}k\ \ \rm roots\\x\equiv s_1,\ldots,s_{\large\color{}{\ell}}\pmod n,\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \,\color{#c00}{\ell}\ \ \rm roots\end{array}\\[.3em] 
&\iff& \left\{ \begin{array}{}x\equiv r_{\large i}\pmod{\! m}\\x\equiv s_{\large j}\pmod n\end{array} \right\}\ \ \ \ {\rm for}\ \  \begin{array}{}1 \le i \le k\\ 1\le j\le\ell\end{array}\\
&\overset{\rm\large CRT\!}\iff& \left\{ x\equiv t_{\,\large i\, j}\!\!\!\!\pmod{\!mn} \right\}\,\ \ \underbrace{{\rm for}\ \ 1 \le i\le k,\,\ 1\le j\le\ell}_{\Large \color{#c00}{k\,\cdot\, \ell}\ \,\rm roots\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ }\\
\end{eqnarray}\qquad\qquad$$

Comment: so how do I conclude that the number of solutions is greater than any s?

Comment: @Phi_24 By above, if we multiply the modulus by a new prime $\,p>2\,$ we $\rm\color{#c00}{double}$  the number of roots, since $\,(x\!-\!1)(x\!+\!1)\,$ has $\,\color{#c00}2\,$ roots $\,\pm1\pmod{\!p}.\,$  But by Euclid there are *infinitely* many primes, so we can repeatedly double the number of roots beyond any bound.