# Quadratic residue and Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem, quadratic-residues

I have been casually reading a set of [notes](https://tartarus.org/gareth/maths/notes/ii/Number_Theory_2011.pdf) (page 30 in reader) on number theory, but I am not certain on one of the steps in the reasoning. Here is a quote:

> What can we say about $w^2 ≡ −3\mod 4n$? Let’s study the case when $n = p$ is an odd prime. By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, there is a solution to $w^2 ≡ −3\mod 4p$ iff there is a solution to:
>
> $$w^2\equiv -3 \mod 4$$
> $$w^2  \equiv -3 \mod p$$
>
> There is clearly a solution to $w^2 ≡ −3\mod 4$, namely $w = 1$. So we
> can concentrate on $w^2 ≡ (−3)\mod p$. This has a solution iff $p=3$ or $\Big(\frac{-3}{p}\Big)=1$.

The author then simplifies the Legendre symbol to deduce that $p=3$ or $p \equiv 1 \mod 3$. However, this solution is not going to be $w=1$, as it was for the first congruence. As far as I can see, what the author proves is that there are solutions $u,v$ such that:

$$u^2\equiv -3 \mod 4$$
$$v^2  \equiv -3 \mod p$$

for $p$ as specified, but it is not clear to me how these separate existence results imply a solution to $w^2 ≡ −3\mod 4p$ even with the Chinese Remainder Theorem. Isn't it also necessary to show that at least one of the solutions $v$ to the congruence mod $p$ is congruent to $\pm 1 \mod 4$?

Comment: @BillDubuque Right, but I don't see how it follows immediately from CRT.

Comment: @BillDubuque That if the solutions in the separate congruences are squares, the solution in the combined congruence can also be a square? To apply CRT to $x = w^2$, it seemed to me that we would need $u^2 = v^2 = w^2$.

Comment: See the [Remark here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1262457/242) for how CRT works to lift roots of polynomial equations (e.g. $\,f(x) = x^2+3\,$ here).

Comment: @BillDubuque Ok, thank you. I may have missed it, but I think this corollary was not explicitly given in the text I am reading.

Comment: It's a simple application of CRT (which will become clearer when you learn about product rings).

Comment: @BillDubuque Your answer for the other question does answer mine, but is it really a duplicate? I don't mind this being closed but the questions really do not appear to be the same (at least, to someone with no significant experience with number theory). Anyway, thanks again. (I have learnt about product rings, actually, but in a more abstract context, I guess.)

Comment: See [abstract duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1756/242)

Comment: @BillDubuque Ah, okay.