# A nonzero polynomial has no more roots than its degree over a domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $K$ be an integral domain, and consider a polynomial $f$ in $K[x]$ with degree $\deg(f) \leq n$. Suppose there exist $n + 1$ pairwise distinct elements $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_{n+1} \in K$ such that $f(\alpha_i) = 0$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n + 1$. Prove that $f$ must be the zero polynomial.

So the proof goes as follows:

Let's suppose $f\ne 0$. We have $f(\alpha_1)=0\Rightarrow f=(x-\alpha_1)q_1$ for some $q_1\in K[x]$. Let's take $f(\alpha_2)=(\alpha_2-\alpha_1)q_1(\alpha_2)$. As $K$ is an integral domein and $\alpha_2-\alpha_1\ne0$, then $q_1(\alpha_2)=0$. Then $q_1=(x-\alpha_2)q_2$ for some $q_2\in K[x]$. So $$f=(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)\dots(x-\alpha_{n+1})q_{n+1}, q_{n+1}\in K[x],$$ which contradicts $\deg(f)\le n$.

I can't really tell what's the specific property of integral domains that is needed for this result. Where are we using that $K$ is an integral domain (a commutative ring with identity which does not have divisors of zero)? We know that $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{n+1}$ are pairwise distinct, so of course $\alpha_2-\alpha_1\ne0$. Why can't $K$ be just a ring?

Comment: Okay now the related question HAS NOTHING TO DO with my question. I think I am being personally targeted right now.

Comment: It uses the fact that *nonzero elements are cancellable* in a domain, i.e. $a_2\neq a_1\Rightarrow a_2-a_1\neq 0\,$ so $(a_2-a_1)q(a_2)=0\Rightarrow q(a_2)=0.\,$ This  is highlighted in the proof of the [Bifactor Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/868550/242) in the linked dupe (where a counterexample is given in non-domains).

Comment: I found a counterexample. Let's $f(x)=x^2-\overline1\in\mathbb{Z}_8$. We have $f(\overline3)=\overline0, f(\overline1)=\overline0, f(\overline5)=\overline0,$ but the degree of $f$ is $2$. But I still don't understand where in this line of the proof: "As $K$ is an integral domein and $\alpha_2-\alpha_1\ne0$, then $q_1(\alpha_2)=0$" we're using that $K$ is a domain.

Comment: That's the same non-domain counterexample that I linked in my prior comment.

Comment: @BillDubuque, well I didn't see it directly from what you wrote. But what does cancellable in a domain mean? I really don't understand how we used it in the proof.

Comment: @BillDubuque, we know that $a_1-a_2\ne0$ as they are pairwise distinct.

Comment: The proof *cancels* a nonzero element, which is valid only because we are in a *domain*, i.e it uses $\,ab=0,\ a\neq 0\Rightarrow b = 0,\,$ for $\,a = \alpha_2-\alpha_1,\ b = q(\alpha_2).\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque, thank you, I appreciate it. I understood it now.

Comment: @BillDubuque, may I also ask you if $\mathbb{Z_8}$ is a commutative ring with unity?

Comment: You might find helpful [this constructive variant](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4604/242) which shows how to split $n$ into nontrivial factors given a nonzero polynomial over $\,\Bbb Z/n\,$ with more roots than its degree. The Theorem there shows that being a domain is equivalent to this property of roots.

Comment: @SAQ Just to add for example the polynomial $x^2-4$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{21}[x]$ has $2,13,5$ as roots

Comment: Note $\,a\neq 0,\ ab=0\,\Rightarrow\, b=0\,$ is viewable as $\color{#c00}{{\rm cancelling}\ a},\,$ because $\,0 = a\cdot 0,\,$ written explicitly we have that $\,\color{#c00}a\color{#0a0}b = \color{#c00}a\cdot\color{#0a0} 0\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#0a0}{b=0}.\ $ Why do you doubt that $\,\Bbb Z_8\,$ Is commutative ring with $1?\ \ $

Comment: @IrbidMath No, the *correct* values are $\bmod 21\!:\, \sqrt{4}\equiv \pm 2,\pm5 \equiv 2,5,16,19,\ $ See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1262457/242) for how to compute them via CRT.

Comment: @BillDubuque you are pushing yourself so hard am not trying to find all solution and I made a mistake. Take it easy.