# Which of these congruences have solutions?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, legendre-symbol

> $$x^2 \equiv 134 \text{ mod } 197$$
>   $$x^2 \equiv  134 \text{ mod }  197^2\times 67$$
>   $$x^2 \equiv  134 \text{ mod }  197^{30}\times2^{10}$$
>   $$x^2 \equiv  134 \text{ mod }  197\times 23^2$$

The firs one has a solution as the Legendre symbol gives 1, but I never got around understanding the other ones.

I notice that $134=2\times67$ but I am not quite sure how to use that for the other parts

Comment: Perhaps with that last line I can deduce that 2 and 3 will also have solutions but the last one will not because there, the 23 causes trouble?

Comment: see the answer for this link (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335179/quadratic-congruence-with-chinese-remainder-thm). This will guide you!