# Incongruent Solutions of a Quadratic congruence

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem, quadratic-residues, congruence-relations

I have been reading up on finding incongruent solutions of quadratic congruences and have stumbled upon an answer to a question asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335179/quadratic-congruence-with-chinese-remainder-thm). The answer I am confused about is the following:

"if you have $x^2 \equiv 23 \pmod {77}$, then we need to look at $x^2 \equiv 23 \pmod 7$ and $x^2 \equiv 23 \pmod{11}$ i.e. $x^2 \equiv 2 \pmod 7$ and $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$.
$$x^2 \equiv 2 \pmod7 \implies x \equiv \pm 3 \pmod 7$$ Similarly, $$x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{11} \implies x \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{11}$$

Hence,
$$x \equiv 3 \pmod 7 \text{ and } x \equiv 1 \pmod{11} \implies x \equiv 45 \pmod{77}$$
$$x \equiv -3 \pmod 7 \text{ and } x \equiv 1 \pmod{11} \implies x \equiv 67 \pmod{77}$$
$$x \equiv 3 \pmod 7 \text{ and } x \equiv -1 \pmod{11} \implies x \equiv 10 \pmod{77}$$
$$x \equiv -3 \pmod 7 \text{ and } x \equiv -1 \pmod{11} \implies x \equiv 32 \pmod{77}$$

Hence,
$$x \equiv \pm 10, \pm 32 \pmod{77}"$$
I understand most of the answer up until the point where the chosen answers are only $$ \pm 10, \pm 32 \pmod{77}.$$

Can someone help me understand why 45 and 67 are not proper answers? I attempted to understand the differences between each answer but as far as I see, they have the same properties relative to the original question. I checked the gcd for each answer and all are relatively prime. (P.S:I would leave a comment on the actual post but it was active back in 2013 and I am unsure if I would get a response leaving a comment on a post that old)

Comment: $\bmod 77\!:\,\ 45\equiv -32,\,\ 67\equiv -10,\,$ so they are congruent to the listed solutions.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1262457/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2041335/242) for further detail on the underlying method (lifting roots using CRT).

Comment: Thank you so much for your responses! So then it would also be correct to have the final answers stay as 45,67,10 and 32 right?

Comment: Yes, you can choose any integer congruent to a root as its representative. The OP's choice corresponds to used a balanced (least-magnitude) system of reps, e.g. $\: \pm\{0,1,2,3\}\pmod 7\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

$45$ and $67$ are perfectly proper answers, and in some contexts (but not all contexts) its conventional usage would require answers to be in the set $\{0,1,2,\ldots,77-1\},$ so that that way of writing the answers would be required. However, it seems that someone wanted to emphasize the role of $\text{“} {\pm} \text{”}$ in the solutions to $x^2\equiv\cdots,$ and that's certainly a thing one should be aware of.